# Shell script fails when executed by systemd service

Tags: linux, bash, shell, xorg, systemd

So I have a systemd service called startup.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=startup scripts

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/home/user/Documents/Tools/Scripts/startup.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

that calls a script called startup.sh:

```
#! /bin/sh -
DIR='/home/user/Documents/Tools/Scripts'
$DIR/audio.sh
$DIR/powertop.sh
$DIR/xinput.sh
```

which calls a script called xinput.sh:

export DISPLAY=:0.0
if xinput set-prop 11 297 -107 -107; then
echo "done!"
fi

When I run startup.sh as root, xinput.sh returns "done!" and correctly changes the settings. When I run startup.service as root, xinput fails and returns:

```
Jun 23 22:37:45 localhost startup.sh[7051]: No protocol specified
Jun 23 22:37:45 localhost startup.sh[7051]: Unable to connect to X server
```

(This is all after X has started)

What's the difference? Why is this happening?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111831/cannot-connect-to-x-server-0-0-as-superuser

Comment: Setting Xauthority fixed it. I still don't know why running the script is different from running the unit.

Comment: Meant to say service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between running the script via `systemd` and running it directly it directly is the environment. You can test it like this. In your Unit file, add this to the [Service] section, for testing:

```
StandardOutput=console
```

Then in your bash script, at the top add this line to dump the environment:

```
env
```

Now run the script inside and outside of systemd and compare the environment variables that are dumped.

It's a feature of systemd that it tightly controls the environment. This both improves security and provides consistency.